# Virtual Host under MacOSX not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mac

I have setup a virtualhost for MacOSX Apache installation.

These are my steps:

- edit /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf removing comment from:

  ```
  Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```
- edit /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.local
DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/Test/public"
<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/Test/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- edit /private/etc/hosts added

  ```
  127.0.0.1 test.local
  ```
- Restart Apache

But the VirtualHost does not work. To further isolate the problem, I check the same configuration with `MAMP` and the virtual host worked right, so the configuration files should be fine.

What can be wrong?

Comment: I can't spot any obvious mistakes in your config file, but you might like to try [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) for Mac OSX. It greatly simplifies creating Apache virtual hosts.

Comment: @Nick Excellent recommendation, but I'm trying to learn the thing from the ground up so I prefer for now stick to manual editing. I will anyway check the app for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your config has wrong IP?

```
127.0.0.7 test.local
```

This one should work just fine:

```
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

Additionally you may have incorrect `<VirtualHost>` directives formatting (**unless** this is happened when you inserted text here). Instead of

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
Includes AllowOverride All
```

should be

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Excuse me, I have corrected the errors in the post. My configuration were correct, but I add some mistakes when formating the text of the post.

Comment: @David This config looks absolutely fine to me. When you say "does not work" -- what do you mean exactly/how it does not work?

Comment: I'll point the browser to test.local and he cannot find the address. I have created the folders Test/public and a test index.html file inside public. May be a permisions issue?, although as I have pointed the same configuration worked under MAMP instalation.

Comment: @David I'm not a Mac user so cannot really advice much here. Config is fine .. what error log say, anything at all?

Comment: There should be some other error becouse localhost was also falling to load. I reset the conf files to original state and localhost now works. I have a diferent problem now, but I will start a new post. Thanks.